# How to find all possible options in C?

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to find a efficient algorithm in C, which provides me all options of a given equation.

I have equation AX + BY = M, where A, B and M i got on input (scanf).

```
For example lets have: 5X + 10Y = 45
```

- 1st option: 5 * 9 + 10 * 0
- 2nd option: 5 * 7 + 10 * 1
- n-th option: 5 * 1 +
  10 * 4

And also I need to count how many possible options exist?
Some tips, hints?

I forgot to say that X and Y are in Z and >= 0, so there is no infinite options.

Comment: Do the values of X,Y have to be +ve, coz if not, there are infinite solutions.

Comment: Equations such as these are called `diophantine equations`. Google this term for more details.

Comment: This is a mathematical problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematical problem.

Comment: It's even a mathematical problem that isn't well stated. Many answers make (good) assumtions that the results can only be positive (or non-negative) integers, but that should be part of the problem statement.

Comment: To make this a coding issue, suggest restricting variables to `int` and posting your sample code.

Answer (score 3):

The question makes sense if you restrict to non-negative unknowns.

Rewrite the equation as

```
AX = M - BY.
```

There can be positive solutions as long as the RHS is positive, i.e.

```
BY ≤ M,
```

or

```
Y ≤ M/B.
```

Then for a given Y, there is a solution iff

```
A|(M - BY)
```

You can code this in Python as

```
for Y in range(M / B + 1):
    if (M - B * Y) % A == 0:
        X= (M - B * Y) / A
```

The solutions are

```
9 0
7 1
5 2
3 3
1 4
```

The number of iterations equals `M / B`. If `A > B`, it is better to swap `X` and `Y`.

Answer (score 0):

you can calcule every solution if you put some limit in your input value, for example: use `X` and `Y` in a value included from `0` to `9`... in this way you can use `for` to calculate every solution.

Answer (score 0):

The number of solution is infinite:

1. find a first solution like: `X=9, Y=0`.
2. you can create another solution by using:

   ```
   X' = X+2*p
   Y' = Y-p
   ```

   For any `p in Z`.

This proves your program will never terminate.